# Spring Data MongoDB: update using dot-notation

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

I'll put my question simple, so excuse me...

**Does Spring Data MongoDB support dot-notation in update queries?**

I've tried to execute this snipet:

```
Query query = new Query(Criteria.where("_id").is(id));
Update update = new Update();
update.set("value.version",version);
mongoOperations.updateFirst(query, update, Audit.class);
```

And found no expected changes in `Audit` collection. What am I missing?

Comment: dot notation should work properly in spring-data. I tested here and successfully update a field using dot notation. Are you sure that exists an document with the id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My mistake was that I didn't realize that `id` in `is()` part of query criteria must be ObjectId. For some reason Spring Data does automatic conversion from ObjectId to BigInteger, but not from BigInteger to ObjectId.

If someone knows how to convert it manually, please answer [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17530485/spring-data-mongodb-biginteger-to-objectid-conversion)